# Is there a way to have 1 to many relationship join in Big Query? I want to repeat values using full outer join but it returns inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have a table with a ranking keywords and join another table where the keyword exists but when I apply an outer join, it only returns the inner join since there are multiple matches to 1.

What I have:
[image]

What I want:

[image]

I tried several different joins but it doesn't return what I want. It always returns an inner join.

Comment: Hi @Mike Naran, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired output by [joining](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join_types) each table separately and then applying [union](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#union_example) on those results.You can try the below query :

**Query:**

```
 create temp table main as (
 select 1 ranking, 'apple' keyword, 500 total_purchase union all
 select 2,'banana', 477  union all
 select 3, 'milk', 456
);
 
create temp table t1 as (
 select 1 ranking, 'apple' keyword, 55 purchase, 1 store union all
 select 2,'beer', 42 ,1  union all
 select 3, 'chips', 33 ,1
);
 
create temp table t2 as (
 select 1 ranking, 'apple' keyword, 51 purchase, 2 store union all
 select 2,'banana', 43 ,2  union all
 select 3, 'bread', 34 ,2
);
 
select m.*,t.purchase,first_value(Store ignore nulls) over
( order by m.ranking) store from main m
left join t1 t on m.keyword = t.keyword
union all
select m.*,t.purchase,first_value(Store ignore nulls) over( order by 
m.ranking) store from main m
left join t2 t on m.keyword = t.keyword
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Yeah the store tables are actually all 1 table so it has to be 1 to many relationship for it to work but when I apply an outer join in only returns an inner join because many items can match to 1 item in a ranking table. I